# Character Moves Too Fast

Tags: java

I am developing a game where I have a speed variable and a player x and player y.

Here is the up directional movement for my player:

I use an `if` statement in my `up` method in order to check if the player is breaking the boundaries of my frame.

```
public void createCharacter(Player player) {
    Character.player = player;
    speed = 1;
    character.setIcon(CharacterSheet.downRightLeg);
    Game.game.add(character);
    px = 200;
    py = 200;
    character.setBounds(px, py, 56, 63);
}

public static void up() {
    if (py - 2 > 0) {
        player.setPlayerDirection(1);
        py -= speed;
        renderUpwardWalking();
        character.setLocation(px, py);
        Game.user.setLocation(px, py - 50);
    } else if (py - 2 < 0) {
    }
}
```

I call `createCharacter` at the beginning of the game when a player logs in.

Can I set int `speed` to a double and give it a value like .5?  I tried it and it didn't work.  My character moves too fast for the game I'm making and I don't know how to slow him down.

Comment: you need to set px and py to doubles as well.

Comment: I think you are using a timer (or a thread) to move your character. So why don't you decrease the delay instead of using a double? A double is perfectly acceptable but is useless in your specific case

Comment: @BackSlash using doubles is still useful if you want different things to move at different speeds. For example, being able to only-just outrun an enemy.

Comment: @Dave, I set my px and py to a double and it works :)  Thank you!  As for BackSlash I am using a timer to check for playermovement.  Is that what you are referring to?  And is decreasing the delay on it more efficient than the double?

Comment: @Dave, exactly my thinking.  I will use the same set-up for enemies.